# How To Use Next Link for Routing to Avoid Page Refresh

Tags: next.js, routes, next-link

Below is the code for my navbar:

```js
    'use client'
    
    import { useState } from 'react';
    import { GiHamburgerMenu } from 'react-icons/gi';
    import Link from 'next/link';
    import Image from 'next/image';
    
    const Header = () => {
      const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    
      const toggleMenu = () => {
        setIsOpen(!isOpen);
      };
    
      return (
        <header className="bg-gray-800 p-4 fixed w-full top-0 z-10">
          <div className="container mx-auto flex justify-between items-center">
            <div className="flex items-center">
              <Link legacyBehavior href="/">
              <a>
              <Image
                    src="/logo.svg"
                    width={100}
                    height={100}
                    alt="logo"
                    />
                </a>
              </Link>
            </div>
            <div className="md:hidden">
              <GiHamburgerMenu className="text-white text-2xl cursor-pointer" onClick={toggleMenu} />
            </div>
            <nav className={`md:hidden absolute top-16 left-0 w-full bg-gray-800 p-8 transition-all ${isOpen ? 'block' : 'hidden'}`}>
            <NavLink href="/" text="Home" onClick={toggleMenu} />
              <NavLink href="/menu" text="Menu" onClick={toggleMenu} />
              <NavLink href="/about" text="About" onClick={toggleMenu} />
              <NavLink href="/contact" text="Contact" onClick={toggleMenu} />
            </nav>
            <div className="md:flex md:ml-auto md:items-center hidden">
            <NavLink href="/" text="Home" />
              <NavLink href="/menu" text="Menu" />
              <NavLink href="/about" text="About" />
              <NavLink href="/contact" text="Contact" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
      );
    };
    
    const NavLink = ({ href, text, onClick }) => (
      <Link legacyBehavior href={href}>
        <a className="text-white hover:text-gray-300 px-4 py-2 rounded-md block" onClick={onClick}>{text}</a>
      </Link>
    );
    
    export default Header;
```

This is my page.js code:

```js
    import Image from "next/image";
    import Header from "./components/Header";
    import HomeSection from "./components/HomeSection";
    import Menu from "./components/Menu";
    
       export default function Home() {
          return (
           <>
              <Header />
              <HomeSection />
              <Menu />
              </>
          );
        }
```

How can I write my code better and get better navigation without having a full page refresh? Also, when I click the menu on the navbar it's redirecting me to 404
This page could not be found. [Here](https://restaurant-beta-omega.vercel.app/) is a deployed version of the project. [Here](https://github.com/Wachira2000/restaurant-beta) is my project folder structure. However, the project is not yet complete. I would love to collaborate with someone willing to help me with the issues I'm facing. Drop your GitHub username or email so that can add you.

Comment: Is that only 404 page refreshes or an actual page which you have a route defined as well ?

Comment: Please add folder structure.

Comment: @Beast80K Find my folder structure [here] (https://github.com/Wachira2000/restaurant-beta)

Answer (score 0):

**Problems :**

> 1. navigation without having a full page refresh?
> 2. when I click the menu on the navbar it's redirecting me to 404

**Causes:**

- **Use Link component** from NextJS to navigate to a page without refresh,
- **Improper folder structure**, NextJS uses folder names as page name & it(folder) contains a file page.js which is actually the page, hence when you try to navigate to `/Menu` it tries to find folder name as Menu which is not there according to your folder structure.

**Solution :**

**Steps :**

- Create folder `Menu`, under `app` folder. Then add a file in it as page.js.
- Do same, for other pages. Make folder with page names, & add a file in it as page.js.

**Replace:**

```
<NavLink href="/menu" text="Menu" />
```

by

```
<Link href="/menu">Menu</Link>
```

**Here's a small example :**

**Folder Structure (excluded unnecessary):**

```
projectname
├── src
│   └── app
│       ├── comp    // Components folder
│       │   ├── Menus
│       │   │   └── Menus.js
│       │   └── MyNavBar
│       │       └── MyNavBar.js   
│       ├── globals.css
│       ├── layout.js      // add Navbar here, so its visible in all pages
│       ├── menu           // menu page folder
│       │   └── page.js    // menu page file
│       └── page.js        // home page (http://localhost:3000/)
└── tailwind.config.js
```

**layout.js :**

```
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import './globals.css'
import MyNavBar from './comp/MyNavBar/MyNavBar'


const inter = Inter({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  variable: '--inter',
  display: 'swap',
})


export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" className={`${inter.variable}`} >
      <body className={`bg-background font-Inter scroll-smooth`}>
        <MyNavBar />

        {children}

      </body>
    </html >
  )
}
```

**Components :**

**Menus.js** at `src\app\comp\Menus\Menus.js` :

```
'use client'
import React from 'react'

const Menus = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Menus</h3>

            <ul>
                <li>A</li>
                <li>B</li>
                <li>C</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Menus
```

**MyNavBar.js** at `src\app\comp\MyNavBar\MyNavBar.js` :

```
'use client'

import Link from 'next/link'
import React from 'react'

const MyNavBar = () => {
    return (
        <div className='flex gap-4 items-center'>
            <Link href={"/"}>Home</Link>
            <Link href={"/menu"}>Menu</Link>
            <Link href={"/about"}>About</Link>
            <Link href={"/contact"}>Contact</Link>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MyNavBar
```

menu page at `src\app\menu\page.js` :

```
import Menus from "../comp/Menus/Menus";

export default function MenuPg() {
    return (
        <h1>
            Menu Page
            <Menus />
        </h1>
    );
}
```

**Explaination :**

- Go to url `http://localhost:3000/`, you will see header. Click on menu link,
- `http://localhost:3000/menu` you will see `Menus component` output.

*Do the same for remaining links*

**Please Read :**

- **App Router** : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing#the-app-router
- **Roles of Folders and Files :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing#roles-of-folders-and-files
- **File Conventions :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing#file-conventions
- **Link :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/link
- **Routing Fundamentals :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing
- **Linking and Navigating :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating

> ***If you still have any doubts, leave a comment.***